# Foreground Service is getting stopped after few hours by OS (Redmi note 8)

Tags: java, android, service, foreground

I need a help. How do you run foreground service in Chinese phones? I've followed documentations of android and it worked on other phones like samsung smoothly. But Failed In Xiaomi, Vivo.
Note: I have no memory leaks in my code.
In Xiaomi I have whitelisted the app and put no restrictions on battery. But still doesn't work. It worked for only 2-3 hours. Then got stopped by OS.
Provide a solution in Java or Guide me in your words. Thank you

Comment: Services don't last forever.  If you need that, you need a different OS instead of Android.  A service, including a foreground service, can be killed at any time.  Foreground services are given more leniency, but you can't count on them forever.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.